# How to implement a getBounds() method in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, implementation

I created a custom DisplayObject that extends from "Sprite" and i need to override the getBounds() method.

```
getBounds(targetCoordinateSpace:DisplayObject):Rectangle
```

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to determine the bounds relative to any other DisplayObject.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Why do you ever need to overwrite this function?

Comment: The bounds are supposed to be defined only by some children of the parent Sprite, not all of them.

Comment: Perhaps you could try a trickier way? Either split the content of your Display object up into 2 parts, one part will contain the children you want to count, and the other will contain the children you don't want to count. Then just call get bounds on the one you want. Another possible way is to keep track of the children you don't want to count, before you call to get bounds hide/remove the unwanted children, get bounds, then add them back? Just some ideas.